# how to return number as float number es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Well, im trying to return all my number in a specific format

```
Number(parseFloat(number).toFixed(fractionalDigits || 2))
```

this  works fine but in some cases fails,  here are some result

1.111 returns "1.11" and after converting it to number it will be returned 1.11
 as float which is right,
but 2.2 returns "2.20" **and after converting it to number it will be** 2.2  **i need it to be 2.20 as float**

100 returns "100.00" because of toFixed Function and after converting it to number it back to 100 **i need it 100.00 but as float**

how can i do that ?

Comment: `2.20 ==== 2.2`

Comment: You want to format the number when printing it, not change its internal representation.

Comment: i need it in a specific format ! but i need it as float

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

Floats are numeric values, and there is no numerical difference between `2.2` and `2.20`.

When outputting a float, it is converted to a string for display, and that will be the number in its simplest form. That is, `2.2`, since the trailing `0` has no significance.

You wouldn't want `00000002.20000000`, would you? Leading zeroes are just as useless.

If you want trailing zeroes to be displayed, use `toFixed()`. That's what the function is for. What you have right now is converting some arbitrary input (which for all we know is already numerical) into a float, then from a float to a string with a fixed number of decimal places, then back to a float again. All you've achieved is to truncate the number.

Answer (score 2):

For the result you want remove fractionDigits from parameter and remove the las should work

```
parseFloat(number).toFixed(2)
```

the external Number() was not required as you already parsed number as float.Hope it helps

what was happening was the Number function was removing unnecessary 0 that the toFixed was putting in.